changing text of element only when condition is fullfiled
I need to change text of <span data-testid="recapItemPrice">ZADARMO</span> from 'ZADARMO' to 'DOHODOU' only when there is text in parental element 'INDIVIDUÁLNA CENA PREPRAVY na vyžiadanie'
HTML is like this:
<strong data-testid="recapDeliveryMethod">                                                            
<span data-testid="recapItemPrice">ZADARMO</span>
INDIVIDUÁLNA CENA PREPRAVY na vyžiadanie</strong>

I tried this:
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
if ( $("[data-testid=recapDeliveryMethod]").text() === "INDIVIDUÁLNA CENA PREPRAVY na vyžiadanie" ) {
    $("[data-testid=recapItemPrice]").text("DOHODOU");
}
});
</script>

I'm new to JavaScript / jQuery and will appreciate every advice.

Please share what is the current issue you are facing, like text not being changed, or gets reversed etc.

For single text just check if the parents text content contains your search string:
const $child = $("[data-testid=recapItemPrice]");

if ($child.parent().text().includes("INDIVIDUÁLNA CENA PREPRAVY na vyžiadanie")) {
  $child.text("DOHODOU");
}


